# Как удалить программу без Root?

Tags: android

Как удалить программу которая установлена без Root?
Может как-то можно через командную строку это сделать?

Comment: уточните вопрос, через командную строку через adb, с терминала устройства или вызовом из другой программы.

Comment: @pavel, из самого приложение, если там как то можно ADB ввести то было бы не плохо.

Comment: Из приложения никак, ну законным способом только если у вас есть гугл ключ (нужны специальные права). А не совсем - то прописаться администратором устройства по принципу троянов. Через root - su pm uninstall [package] . Или через adb эта же команда.

Comment: @pavel, А можно как то закинуть в Xbin какой нибудь файл допустим...И после чтобы adb заработало.

Просто нет универсального и простого способа рут сделать. Для всех устройств

Comment: Ну спобов получить рут много, самый простой способ - перепрошить телефон. И да, только сейчас подумал вам совсем тихо надо удалять или чтбы пользователь согласие дал тоже устроит?

Comment: @pavel, с согласием и без рута можно. Ну как тихо, не тихо. При запуске приложения, будет 1 единственный запрос, а после уже тихо.... Вот так хотелось бы.... Но без рута((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root - su-права. Если из-под обычного пользователя удалить программу не удаётся, значит для этого нужен root-доступ

Comment: А зачем вы ответ написали? Я же написал без root. И такой способ есть.

Comment: @xTIGRx если такой способ есть, и вы его знаете - то поделитесь ответом. иначе зачем было задавать вопрос?

Comment: @PashaPash, Я слышал от другого форумчанина что есть такой способ. Но как сделать он мне не сказал. Так что и вам не могу подсказать